# xrandr preservation

Tags: display, xrandr, multi-monitor, resolution

I don't know why. I don't know how. But my xrandr is really screwed up. I thought I finally found a graphics driver that wasn't bugged to all heck, but no. It can get seriously bugged.

So a background. When I wake my computer from sleep, it would load with the wrong resolutions. It would change from 1920x1080 and 1600x900 to 1024x768 and 1600x900 in the dual monitor set up. I used to just run a very simple ~/.xprofile command from terminal if that happened to just get the resolution back.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1600x900+0+0 --rate 59.98
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080+1600+880 --rate 60 --primary
```

Okay, great. That would usually fix it until the computer slept again. But then that stopped working suddenly. For whatever reason, maybe some update to the system, it said that that mode value was unrecognized. So I had to change it to

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1600x900 --pos 0x0 --rate 59.98
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1600x880 --rate 60 --primary
```

This worked for a while. But then all of a sudden on one of the executions, I discovered the world of panning. I had never done panning on any OS before, I don't like it.

No duckduckgo result ever says how you disable panning. So I took a couple guesses.

I tried this

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1600x900 --pos 0x0 --panning 1600x900 --rate 59.98
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1600x880 --panning 1920x1080 --rate 60 --primary
```

Basically just match the panning to the intended resolution. This ended up working for a little bit.

And somewhere in all this I'm fighting my graphics drivers with constant install and reboot to figure out if any driver was stable enough to not require me using the terminal to reset my resolution with every wake.

I thought I found one! An Nvidia 470. It was stable for weeks.

But today, it got screwed up. My resolution was all wrong. My monitors overlapped. They both panned. It was god awful. I run the terminal command and... the resolutions go back to correct, but the monitors are still overlapping, and there is still panning.

Complete crap.

Somehow through a miracle of just monkeying around, my Settings -> Displays feature finally worked. I set it to single display, saved, then set it back to dual (joint) display and repositioned the monitors to not overlap, and it worked. Okay, great.

But my ~/.xprofile is broken. I don't know how to fix it to just keep using the same output as I currently have. I want to freeze the current settings so they never change, and if they do ever change, I want to put them back to this exact configuration.

What xrandr commands do I need to do that?

This is my xrandr output.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3520 x 1839, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 435mm x 237mm
   1600x900      59.98*+  74.89    60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00    60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1600+759 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Please after months of blasting .xprofile with xrandr parameters it loves to ignore, what have I been missing? What is the correct way to set my computer to:

Top left monitor is at 0x0 with resolution 1600x900. Bottom right monitor as primary is at 1600x880 with resolution 1920x1080. No overlap. No panning. Just simple. Easy. Standard. Oh I guess refresh rate too, close to 60 fps as possible. Nothing outlandish. Nothing fancy.

Again, by some miracle after fighting for 30 minutes and postponing everything I intended to use the computer for, I have my settings in the state I want them. But I fear as soon as the computer sleeps, it'll all blow up again.

Edit: This doesn't work either.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1600x900 --pos 0x0 --rate 59.98 --panning 0x0
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1600x880 --rate 60 --panning 0x0 --primary
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Nothing fancy. Nothing exotic. Just wanted to be vanilla.

Comment: You seem pretty proficient with `xrandr`. Ideally your computer would not even detect and react on a bunch of changes happening at wakeup.—In case you launch a command to get back to your working configuration, don’t forget to mention the error message.

Comment: Except there *is* no error message. Just unexpected and unwanted results.